# Web Scraping New York State Senate Bill's to Create Ideology Score Matrix in Google Sheets

Tags: html, web-scraping, google-sheets

I am currently attempting to find the ideology score for New York State Senate Members using [this](https://www.govtrack.us/about/analysis#ideology) methodology (U.S. Senators). To do so I am attempting to pull the name of Senators who are sponsors and their co-sponsors from [this NYS bill search website](https://nyassembly.gov/leg/?default_fld=&leg_video=&bn=S00070&term=2021&Summary=Y). I am doing this through a [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RPjY_haEmkrANZ7wGX9VJjcEr9rEVlIFRNphGpR0YD8/edit#gid=0). This is working but is taking an extraordinarily long time. Is there any way that I could speed up this process in Google Sheets?

An additional question. Say I compile a sheet that contains the sponsors and their co-sponsors, for a certain number of bills. It would look like the image below. How would I then go about converting this into a sheet, wherein each cell of the table, I put the number of times the senator for the row cosponsored a bill introduced by the senator for the column?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are loading too many times each Bill n° (63 * 2 = 126). Load one time each Bill n° in a specific tab, then apply the search in the relative tab with indirect function. I have prepared 2 Bill n° in this spreadsheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ojs3wOrbw5ww8VTrBOWSLXp7cs53hWPF4AWadayQbow/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

delete all formulae in your sheet

use this in C5:

```
=INDEX(IF($B6:$B="",,IFNA(VLOOKUP(REGEXEXTRACT($B6:$B, " (.*)$"), 
 TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(QUERY(IMPORTHTML(
 "https://nyassembly.gov/leg/?term="&$A$2&"&bn="&C$2, "table", 1), 
 "select Col2 where Col1 matches 'SPONSOR|COSPNSR'"), ","&CHAR(10), 1)&
 {"×Y (Sponsor)"; "×Y"}), "×")), 2, 0), "N")))
```

and drag to the right for about 50 columns. then select those 50 columns (`C6:AZ`) and press **<kbd>CTRL+C</kbd>** then **<kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+V</kbd>** this step is necessary because you got over 500 columns with bills and google sheets has a limit on how many import functions are allowed per spreadsheet (from a test run I made, its 190 imports for me)

[image]

for the count use this in A6:

```
=INDEX(IF(B6:B="",,MMULT(IFERROR(REGEXMATCH(C6:100&"", "Y"), 0)*1, 
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(C6:100))^0)))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12-XXQXuqCbw_kAchvDUyJnPi5E9foal5H3rTvnEcOQQ/edit#gid=0)

### [final sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12-XXQXuqCbw_kAchvDUyJnPi5E9foal5H3rTvnEcOQQ/edit#gid=956548506)

---

#### fun fact lol:

```
total bills:             471
total sponsorships:     1670 out of 29673
total no-sponsorships: 28033 out of 29673
```